# how can we on or off GPS and 3G by clicking on button without going on setting screen in android?

Tags: android

how can we on or off GPS and 3G by clicking on button without going on setting screen in android?

Answer (score 0):

There are widgets to do that. But this question doesn't belong here on SO.